# How to retrieve all the data of users from Firebase Firestore of a mobile app in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

1. [ticket information collection in firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nl3ab.png)
2. [user collection in firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXoja.png)
3. [admin collection in firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hJZZ.png)

The three pictures shown above are the structures of my Firebase Firestore.

The admin collection is used to store the information of the admin after registration. The user collection stored user information after the registration process. At the same time, the ticket information stores the applied ticket information when a user applies for the ticket.

Each user's information is stored under the document named by retrieving their UID and in the collection named "users". Ticket information is stored under the document named by retrieving their UID and in the collection named "ticket_information".

```
//get data from firestore
    DocumentReference documentReference = fStore.collection("users").document(userID);
    documentReference.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
            if(documentSnapshot.exists())
            {
                profile_username.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("fName"));
                profile_email.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("email"));
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(UserProfile.this, "Record not found.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(UserProfile.this, "Failed to fetch data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

This is the code i use to retrieve data from Firestore but I'm not sure that is it possible to retrieve all the information of the users and their related ticket information based on their UID? Thanks if you can help.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how is the "admins" collection related to the "users" and "ticket_information". Can you please explain that?

Comment: The admin collection is used to store the information of the admin after registration. The user collection stored user information after the registration process. While the ticket information stores the applied ticket information when the user applies for the ticket.

Comment: When the user register, the email and name will be stored in the user collection. When the user applied for the ticket, the ticket information such as the date, the mobile phone will be stored in the ticket information collection. When the admin register, the admin information such as admin name and email will be stored in the admin collection.

Comment: The user information and ticket information were stored by using their uid. So, the question is when I log in as admin, can I retrieve the data in user collection and ticket information collection because I want to use the information to make a report. Thanks. Hope you can understand.

Comment: Yes, it's clear now. I'll write you an answer right away.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I only know that the concept of how to retrieve information of a specific person. For example, when user A login, then the user profile will retrieve the data from the user collection and document with the user's special uid using DocumentReference. Take your time and have a nice day.

Comment: Information relevant to the question should be edited into the question, rather than left in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Please read the [site guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on asking questions, particularly on using [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/90527) and [sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to provide the admin access to read the data inside the "users" and "ticket_information" collection, you have to use [Firestore security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started).

Assuming that you have the rules in place, to be able to get all users from the "users" collection allowing with their corresponding tickets, please use the following lines of code:

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference usersRef = db.collection("users");
usersRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                String email = document.getString("email");
                String fname = document.getString("fName");
                String uid = document.getId();
                DocumentReference uidRef = db.collection("ticket_information").document(uid);
                uidRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                            if (document.exists()) {
                                String icPassport = document.getString("ic_passport");
                                String phone = document.getString("phone");
                                String ticketDate = document.getString("ticket_date");

                                Log.d(TAG, email + "/" + fname + "/" + icPassport + "/" + phone + "/" + ticketDate);
                            } else {
                                Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
        }
    }
});
```

The result in the logcat will be:

```
jett@gmail.com/jett/1919191/191991919/9 Oct 2021
//...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try it. I will comment here if I face any problems. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, give it a try and tell me if it works.

Comment: Sir, thanks a lot, it works fine. But when i try to setText(email + "/" + fname + "/" + icPassport + "/" + phone + "/" + ticketDate) to a Textview, it can only show the details of a user. I expected it can show all users' details. Is that any solution for it???

Comment: Good to hear that it worked. A Textview is used to hold a single value. But you can use something like this `textView.append(email + "/" + fname + "/" + icPassport + "/" + phone + "/" + ticketDate + "\n")`, right?

Comment: Thank you, sir. All done. Thank you very much. It helps me alot.